# Variable $x$n in arithmetic expansion

Tags: bash, shell, variables, eval

I come across this tutorial example, especial the line `sum=$(($sum+$x$n))`. What does `$x$n` mean in particular? I suppose $x is referenced but not assigned (undeclared/unset variable), isn't it?

https://linuxhint.com/bash_eval_command/

#### evaltest3.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize the variable $sum with the value 0
sum=0

# Declare a for loop that will iterate for 4 times
for n in {1..4}
do
# Create four variables using eval command
eval x$n=$n

# Add the values of the variable with $sum
sum=$(($sum+$x$n))
done

# Assign `echo` command with string into a variable
command="echo 'The result of the sum='"

# `eval` command print the sum value using variables
eval $command $sum
```

Comment: `$x$n` concatenates the two variables. E.g. after `x=1` and `n=3`, `$x$n` is `13`. The script programmer seemed to think that it uses `x$n` as a variable name, and gets the value of `$x3`, but that's not how it works. Since `$x` isn't set, `$x$n` is the same as `$n`.

Comment: It produces the correct answer, but not for the reason claimed in the comment.

Comment: @Barmar - Since it is talking about `eval`, I guess `eval 'sum=$(($sum+$x'$n'))'` makes sense? I did not know eval with unquoted arguments, like `eval x$n=$n`, works. But why does `eval sum=$(($sum+'$x'$n))` not work?

Comment: Without the quotes, the arithmetic expression is evaluated first, then the result is passed as the argument to `eval`.

Comment: With unquoted arguments, it first replaces all the variables. So it becomes `eval x1=1`

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` for the sum, you can use an indirect variable. `v=x$n` then `sum=$(($sum+${!v}))`

Comment: @Barmar You don't need to use indirect variable either, just `sum=$((sum+x$n))`

Comment: @Philippe I knew arithmetic expressions didn't require you to put `$` before variables, but allowing that mixrure is just weird.

Comment: I agree it's weird, but true.

Comment: @Philippe Now I remember that it does recursive replacement of variables, i.e. it automatically does indirect variables. So this is a consequence of that.

Answer (score 0):

(Does not directly answer your question, but offers an alternative)

Since bash arithmetic allows us to provide variables "without using the parameter expansion syntax" [[Ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)] (i.e. without the `$`), we can write

```sh
for n in {1..4}; do ((sum += n)); done
```

The advantage is that bash handles empty or unset variables as the number zero.